# Can we rewrite definition of derivative $L$ of $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ so that $L$ is on one side of equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

From Tao, *Analysis II*, p. [135](https://books.google.com/books?id=oybkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA135):

> **Definition 6.2.2** (Differentiabiliity). Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$, $f:E\to \mathbf{R}^m$ be a function, $x_0 \in E$ be a point, and let $L:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^m$ be a linear transformation. We say that $f$ is *differentiable at $x_0$ with derivative $L$* if we have $$\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E-{x_0}}\frac{\|f(x)-(f(x_0) + L(x-x_0))\|}{\|x-x_0\|}=0.$$ Here $\|x\|$ is the length of $x$ (as measured in the $l^2$ metric): $$\|(x_1,_2,\ldots,x_n)\| = (x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2)^{1/2}$$

Is it possible to rewrite this definition so we have more simply $L$ on the right-hand side of this equation? (I think if that were possible, then I and other students would find that easier to understand.)

Comment: Yes, but [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) since getting used to this version prepares you for further generalization that does not work the same way the one-dimensional version you are trying to mimic does.  Writing the derivative this way reinforces that $f(x_0) + L(x-x_0)$ is the best linear approximation to $f(x)$ in the (deleted) neighborhood of $x_0$.  You should recognize this as multidimensional analogues of the (Calc I) linearization of $f$ near $x_0$ or the (Calc II) degree $1$ Taylor polynomial of $f$ centered at $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can clarify everything, although a little more general but quite natural: The derivative of Fréchet

Let be two fixed normed spaces $(V,\|\cdot\|_V)$ and $(W,\|\cdot\|_W)$. Let a open $U\subset V$, we will say that $f:U\to W$ is Fréchet-differentiable in $x\in U$ if there exists a continuous linear transformation $L\in\mathcal L(V,W)$ such that $h\in V$, $h\to 0_V$,
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+Lh+r_x(h)$$
for a "residual function" $r_x$ with $\frac{\|r_x(h)\|_W}{\|h\|_V}\to 0$. Equivalently, we ask that $r_x(h)$ satisfy the following
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\;\exists\delta>0:\forall h\in B_V(x,\delta)\subset U,\|r_x(h)\|_W\leq \epsilon\|h\|_V.$$

We will call $L$, the Fréchet derivative of $f$ in $x$ and it is usually written $L=Df(x)$.

As in analysis on the line, you could couple $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ to $f'(x_0)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$, in the same way it is done here.